# PHP and MySQL function return

Tags: php, mysql, function, return

So I have this piece of code, it's for image upload system:

```
return (getBoolPreference('enableField#images@items'));
```

I have never seen # and @ at codes. If you could say what this `return` does and what is the meaning of `#` and `@`, I would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

`'enableField#images@items'` is nothing more than a string for PHP in that syntax. Only your `getBoolPreference` function can tell how that `string` is used in your program.

Your `return` statement returns the output of `getBoolPreference` generated when a string `'enableField#images@items'` is passed to it, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I would like to know what the # and @ are used for